# How to implement zip function using LiveData

Tags: java, android

I'm using twos LiveDatas to get data from my server, and want to result after both LiveData finished?

```java
LiveData live1 = ...;
LiveData live2 = ...;
MutableLiveData live3 = ...;

live1.observe(this, value -> {
    live3.postValue(value);
});

live2.observe(this, value -> {
   live3.postValue(value);
});

live3.observe(this,  value -> {
// TODO: Get both values from live1, live2
}
```

I expect the both values from live1 and live2

Comment: What is the issue? What happens in `live3.observe`?

Comment: Use MediatorLiveData for merging both streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more generalized version which allows you to observe multiple `LiveData`.

```
fun zipLiveData(vararg liveItems: LiveData<*>): LiveData<ArrayList<Any>> {
    //MediatorLiveData used to merge multiple LiveDatas
    return MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<Any>>().apply {
        val zippedObjects = ArrayList<Any>()
        liveItems.forEach {
            //Add each LiveData as a source for the MediatorLiveData
            addSource(it) { item ->
                //Add value to list
                item?.let { it1 -> zippedObjects.add(it1) }
                if (zippedObjects.size == liveItems.size) {
                    //If all the LiveData items has returned a value, save that value in MediatorLiveData.
                    value = zippedObjects
                    //Clear the list for next time
                    zippedObjects.clear()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above function doesn't add `null` values to the list, assuming you want to add `null` value as well, you'd need to do something along the following lines instead,

```
fun zipLiveData(vararg liveItems: LiveData<*>): LiveData<ArrayList<Any?>> {
    return MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<Any?>>().apply {
        val zippedObjects = ArrayList<Any?>()
        liveItems.forEach {
            addSource(it) { item ->
                zippedObjects.add(item)
                if (zippedObjects.size == liveItems.size) {
                    value = zippedObjects
                    zippedObjects.clear()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update** - I just realized that the above methods don't retain the 'order' of the `LiveData` items (so for example, if the second `LiveData` posted a vlaue before the first, you'd get the value `[secondLiveDataValue, firstLiveDataValue]` instead of the expected `[firstLiveDataValue, secondLiveDataValue]`). You could use one of the following two functions instead if you wish to retain the 'order' of `LiveData` item values.

```
//If you know the LiveDatas won't get null values
fun zipLiveData(vararg liveItems: LiveData<*>): LiveData<ArrayList<Any?>> {
    return MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<Any?>>().apply {
        var zippedObjects = arrayOfNulls<Any>(liveItems.size)
        liveItems.forEachIndexed { index, liveData ->
            addSource(liveData) { item ->
                zippedObjects[index] = item
                if (!zippedObjects.contains(null)) {
                    value = zippedObjects.toCollection(ArrayList())
                    zippedObjects = arrayOfNulls(liveItems.size)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Incase your LiveDatas might have null values
fun zipLiveDataWithNull(vararg liveItems: LiveData<*>): LiveData<ArrayList<Any?>> {
    return MediatorLiveData<ArrayList<Any?>>().apply {
        val zippedObjects = arrayOfNulls<Any>(liveItems.size)
        val zippedObjectsFlag = BooleanArray(liveItems.size)
        liveItems.forEachIndexed { index, liveData ->
            addSource(liveData) { item ->
                zippedObjects[index] = item
                zippedObjectsFlag[index] = true
                if (!zippedObjectsFlag.contains(false)) {
                    value = zippedObjects.toCollection(ArrayList())
                    for(i in 0 until liveItems.size) {
                        zippedObjectsFlag[i] = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you need is called `zip` function:

```
fun <A, B> zip(first: LiveData<A>, second: LiveData<B>): LiveData<Pair<A, B>> {
    val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<Pair<A, B>>()

    var isFirstEmitted = false
    var isSecondEmitted = false
    var firstValue: A? = null
    var secondValue: B? = null

    mediatorLiveData.addSource(first) {
        isFirstEmitted = true
        firstValue = it
        if (isSecondEmitted) {
            mediatorLiveData.value = Pair(firstValue!!, secondValue!!)
            isFirstEmitted = false
            isSecondEmitted = false
        }
    }
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(second) {
        isSecondEmitted = true
        secondValue = it
        if (isFirstEmitted) {
            mediatorLiveData.value = Pair(firstValue!!, secondValue!!)
            isFirstEmitted = false
            isSecondEmitted = false
        }
    }

    return mediatorLiveData
}
```

Now, you can call `zip(firstLiveData,secondLiveData)` and observe on it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is somewhat inspired from rxjava zip operator,

```
inline fun <reified I1, I2, O> biZip(inputLiveData1: LiveData<I1>, inputLiveData2: LiveData<I2>, crossinline tranform: (data1: I1, data2: I2) -> O): LiveData<O> {

    var input1: I1? = null
    var input2: I2? = null
    val mediatorLiveData = MediatorLiveData<O>()
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(inputLiveData1) {
        input1 = it
        if (input1 != null && input2 != null) {
            mediatorLiveData.value = tranform.invoke(input1!!, input2!!)
        }
    }
    mediatorLiveData.addSource(inputLiveData2) {
        input2 = it
        if (input1 != null && input2 != null) {
            mediatorLiveData.value = tranform.invoke(input1!!, input2!!)
        }
    }

    return mediatorLiveData
}
```

now you can use it like,

```
val liveDataString = MutableLiveData<String>()
val liveDataInt = MutableLiveData<Int>()

val liveDataofTest = biZip<String, Int, Test>(liveDataString, liveDataInt) { data1:String, data2:Int ->
      return@biZip Test(data1, data2)
}
```

Test pojo is like

`data class Test(val name:String,value:Int)`

Answer (score 1):

This extension function worked for me

```
fun <A, B> LiveData<A>.zipWith(stream: LiveData<B>): LiveData<Pair<A, B>> {
 val result = MediatorLiveData<Pair<A, B>>()
  result.addSource(this) { a ->
    if (a != null && stream.value != null) {
        result.value = Pair(a, stream.value!!)
    }
  }
 result.addSource(stream) { b ->
    if (b != null && this.value != null) {
        result.value = Pair(this.value!!, b)
    }
 }
 return result
}
```

Comment: This is not a zip function, but a combineLatest

Answer (score 0):

You can use it directly like extension function with

```
fun <A, B, C> LiveData<A>.zip(stream: LiveData<B>, func: (source1: A?, source2: B?) -> C): LiveData<C> {
        val result = MediatorLiveData<C>()
        result.addSource(this) { a -> 
            result.setValue(func.invoke(a,stream.value))
        }
        result.addSource(stream) { b -> 
            result.setValue(func.invoke(this.value, b)) 
        }
        return result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer this:

```
fun <T1, T2, R> LiveData<T1>.zipWith(
    other: LiveData<T2>,
    transform: suspend (T1, T2) -> R
): LiveData<R> {
    return asFlow().zip(other.asFlow(), transform).asLiveData()
}
```

If you are trying to move away from LiveData in favor of StateFlow or Flow, you might want to go with something like that.

Also, some of the above solutions didn't work for me even when I confirmed that one of the LiveData properties was being updated.