# Use observe for a variable that updated inside another observe in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am trying first handle the response from API by using observe. Later after observing the handled variable I want to save it to database.

The variable `tokenFromApi` is updated inside `tokenResponseFromApi`'s observer. Is it possible to observe `tokenFromApi` outside the observer of `tokenResponseFromApi`? When debugged, the code did not enter inside `tokenFromApi` observer when the app started.

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {    
    var tokenResponseFromApi: LiveData<String>? = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var tokenFromApi: LiveData<TokenEntity>? = MutableLiveData<TokenEntity>()

    tokenResponseFromApi?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                tokenResponseFromApi ->
            if (tokenResponseFromApi != null) {
                tokenFromApi = viewModel.convertTokenResponseToEntity(tokenResponseFromApi, dh.asDate)
            }
        })

    tokenFromApi?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tokenFromApi ->
        if (tokenFromApi != null) {
            viewModel.saveTokenToDB(repo, tokenFromApi)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: zipWith is your friend

Comment: ah it's LiveData. Quick Google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237829/how-to-implement-zip-function-using-livedata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you're registering the observer on `tokenFromApi` during setup, and when you get your API response, you're *replacing* `tokenFromApi` without registering an observer on it. So if it ever emits a value, you'll never know about it. The only observer you have registered is the one on the discarded `tokenFromApi` which is never used by anything

Honestly your setup here isn't how you're supposed to use `LiveData`. Instead of creating a whole new `tokenFromApi` for each response, you'd just have a single `LiveData` that things can *observe*. When there's a new value (like an API token) you *set* that on the `LiveData`, and all the observers see it and react to it. Once that's wired up, it's done and it all works.

The way you're doing it right now, you have a data source that needs to be taken apart, replaced with a new one, and then everything reconnected to it - every time there's a new piece of data, if you see what I mean.

Ideally the Fragment is the UI, so it reacts to events (by observing a data source like a `LiveData` and pushes UI events to the view model (someone clicked this thing, etc). That API fetching and DB storing really belongs in the VM - and you're already half doing that with those functions in the VM you're calling here, right? The `LiveData`s belong in the VM because they're a source of data about what's going on inside the VM, and the rest of the app - they expose info the UI needs to react to. Having the `LiveData` instances in your fragment and trying to wire them up when something happens is part of your problem

---

Have a look at the [App Architecture guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/ui-layer) (that's the UI Layer page but it's worth being familiar with the rest), but this is a basic sketch of how I'd do it:

```
class SomeViewModel ViewModel() {

    // private mutable version, public immutable version
    private val _tokenFromApi = MutableLiveData<TokenEntity>()
    val tokenFromApi: LiveData<TokenEntity> get() = _tokenFromApi

    fun callApi() {
        // Do your API call here
        // Whatever callback/observer function you're using, do this
        // with the result:
        result?.let { reponse -> 
                convertTokenResponseToEntity(response, dh.asDate)
            }?.let { token ->
                saveTokenToDb(repo, token)
                _tokenFromApi.setValue(token)
            }
    }

    private fun convertTokenResponseToEntity(response: String, date: Date): TokenEntity? {
        // whatever goes on in here
    }

    private fun saveTokenToDb(repo: Repository, token: TokenEntity) {
        // whatever goes on in here too
    }
}
```

so it's basically all contained within the VM - the UI stuff like fragments doesn't need to know anything about API calls, whether something is being stored, how it's being stored. The VM can update one of its exposed `LiveData` objects when it needs to emit some new data, update some state, or whatever - stuff that's interesting to things outside the VM, not its internal workings. The Fragment just `observe`s whichever one it's interested in, and updates the UI as required.

(I know the callback situation might be more complex than that, like saving to the DB might involve a `Flow` or something. But the idea is the same - in its callback/result function, push a value to your `LiveData` as appropriate so observers can receive it. And there's nothing wrong with using `LiveData` or `Flow` objects inside the VM, and wiring those up so a new `TokenEntity` gets pushed to an observer that calls `saveTokenToDb`, if that kind of pipeline setup makes sense! But keep that stuff private if the outside world doesn't need to know about those intermediate steps